# sha1 in Go and PHP has different result

Tags: php, go

PHP Code:

```
$str = chr(164);
$resualt = sha1($str);
echo $resualt;
```

PHP resualt:

```
f5efcd994fca895f644b0ccc362aba5d6f4ae0c6
```

Golang code:

```
str := string(164)
//fmt.Println(str)
passSha1 := sha1.New()
passSha1.Write([]byte(str))
getSha1 := passSha1.Sum(nil)
fmt.Printf("%x\n",getSha1)
```

Golang resualt:

```
fe33a6b4de93e363cf1620f7228df4164d913fbf
```

In Go, how can I get the same result like PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Your php code is encoding a 1-byte input, but your Go code is doing the same on a utf-8 encoded string. If you print `len(string(164))` you'll see that it is 2-bytes. Use this:

```
str := []byte{164}
passSha1 := sha1.New()
passSha1.Write([]byte(str))
getSha1 := passSha1.Sum(nil)
fmt.Printf("%x\n",getSha1)
```